# Owl Carousel not working in Magento 1.8

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, magento, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm having one hell of a time getting Owl Carousel to work on my Magento setup. I've loaded the following into my .xml   [Here is the site](http://www.battingtunnel.com/)

```
<default>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="additem">
        <type>skin_js</type>
        <name>js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js</name>
    </action>

    <action method="additem">
        <type>skin_js</type>
        <name>js/owl.carousel.min.js</name>
    </action>

    <action method="addCss">
        <stylesheet>css/owl.carousel.css</stylesheet>
    </action>

    <action method="addCss">
        <stylesheet>css/owl.theme.css</stylesheet>
    </action>
```

Added the correct files to the folder in Magento.

The follow codes comes up on my site but not plugin.

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div><img src="http://www.battingtunnel.com/media/wysiwyg/owl/owl1.jpg"   alt=""></div>
<div><img src="http://www.battingtunnel.com/media/wysiwyg/owl/owl2.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div><img src="http://www.battingtunnel.com/media/wysiwyg/owl/owl3.jpg"  alt=""></div>
<div><img src="http://www.battingtunnel.com/media/wysiwyg/owl/owl4.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div><img src="http://www.battingtunnel.com/media/wysiwyg/owl/owl5.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div><img src="http://www.battingtunnel.com/media/wysiwyg/owl/owl6.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div><img src="http://www.battingtunnel.com/media/wysiwyg/owl/owl7.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need jQuery to be in noConflict mode otherwise it clashes with the Prototype library which also uses `$` as a variable name in the global namespace.

You could edit your local copy of jQuery-min-1.9.0.js to add the line `jQuery.noConflict();` at the end of the file.

Then check Owl can fall back to `jQuery()` and isn't hard coded to use `$` (if it is, then you can wrap the Owl code in a way that makes a local `$` available to it -- [see the jQuery noConflict docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/))

Then 'all you have to do' is get jQuery to load before prototype.js. I use a modified version of this [Inchoo module](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-external-javascript-css-file-to-magento/). Let me know if you need more directions for getting Prototype and jQuery to work on the same page but I'm sure jQuery needs to load first, then go noConflict to release '$', then prototype.js can load and establish '$' in the global namespace (that is the way I arrange it to happen on Magento sites that use jQuery and Prototype).

Comment: Thanks for the tip!   I'm halfway through classes on Jquery so it is still foreign to me.    I'm sure this will make sense soon.  I will let you know how this works out.

Comment: Great, helps, Jquery must be loaded first, best way is to put it to the layout/page.xml BEFORE prototype: <action method="addJs"><script>jquery.min.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action> ....